# Angularjs testing routes with Karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

In my config of angular I had set the `otherwise` to redirect to a specific location, lets say `/test` so I want to write a test about that, I wrote something like:

```
it("should have a working otherwise route", function() {
  return inject(function($route, $location, $rootScope) {
    var $scope;
    expect($route.current).toBeUndefined();
    $location.path("dsadadasda");
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $scope.$apply()
    expect($location.path()).toBe("/test");
  });
});
```

I am trying to use `location.path` to redirect to a route that does not exist, and then check if angular redirected the user to `/test`. But when I run the test I am getting a `Error: Unexpected request: GET ../server_data/modules.json` error, any idea how can that be solved, or what is the right way to write my test?

**Edit:** The main problem seems to be the `$scope.$apply()`

Edit2: Error

```
        Error: Unexpected request: GET ../server_data/modules.json
        No more request expected
            at $httpBackend (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bower_com
ponents/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1180:9)
            at sendReq (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bower_componen
ts/angular/angular.js:8355:9)
            at $http.serverRequest (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bo
wer_components/angular/angular.js:8088:16)
            at wrappedCallback (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bower_
components/angular/angular.js:11573:81)
            at wrappedCallback (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bower_
components/angular/angular.js:11573:81)
            at c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bower_components/angula
r/angular.js:11659:26
            at Scope.$eval (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bower_comp
onents/angular/angular.js:12702:28)
            at Scope.$digest (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bower_co
mponents/angular/angular.js:12514:31)
            at Scope.$apply (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/bower_com
ponents/angular/angular.js:12806:24)
            at Object.<anonymous> (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/src
/app.routes.spec.js:17:14)
        Error: Declaration Location
            at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-f
rontend/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2146:25)
            at Object.<anonymous> (c:/Users/mavmak/configurator-frontend/app/src
/app.routes.spec.js:12:5)
```

Comment: When do you get the error? Can you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: @user3651406 updated with error stack

Comment: And what does your .config() block look like where you define the route? What puzzles me is, that somehow the $http service tries to load "../server_data/modules.json". I don't think this is standard behaviour.

Comment: I wouldn't test that with unit tests but with protractor.